# A hard(?) 15-X puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Below is the puzzle I came up with before writing [Create a 15-X puzzle with a unique solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125934/71652).

Rules of the puzzle:

- A 6x6 grid is given. Fifteen cells are marked with an X.
- Use polystrips of lengths 1, 2, ..., 8 exactly once each to cover the 6x6 grid. All Xs must be at the endpoint of one of the strips. Polystrips cannot bend twice in a row to cover a 2x2 region.

An [example puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125949/71652) (by hexomino) with solution:

[image]

> [image]

Now solve the following puzzle.

[image]

You can try this puzzle on [Penpa](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/#m=solve&p=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).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the completed grid:

> [image]

Solution path:

> I started off with the obvious deduction:
>  [image]

Next

> I saw that certain squares highlighted in red necessitated this:
>  [image]
>  [image]

Which necessitated

> [image]

> Again there was another necessitated configuration (because of the red square):

> [image]

Which necessitated:

> [image]

> The only way to get a 6 squared strip then led to:
>  [image]
>  The only way to get 5:
>  [image]

> Seeing the remaining strip sizes then it was pretty clear on how to complete the grid:
>  [image]